# Cuda compilation error: class template has already been defined

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cuda, visual-studio-2017, type-traits

I am new to cuda and tried to run a simple vector add sample that I found online to get started. I am using win10 64bit and visual studio 2017.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "cuda.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>


#include <math.h>
// Kernel function to add the elements of two arrays
__global__
void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
    int index = threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x;
    for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
        y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}

int main(void)
{
    int N = 1 << 20;
    float *x, *y;

    // Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
    cudaMallocManaged(&x, N * sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&y, N * sizeof(float));

    // initialize x and y arrays on the host
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        x[i] = 1.0f;
        y[i] = 2.0f;
    }

    // Run kernel on 1M elements on the GPU
    add <<<1, 1 >>>(N, x, y);

    // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // Check for errors (all values should be 3.0f)
    float maxError = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i] - 3.0f));
    std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;

    // Free memory
    cudaFree(x);
    cudaFree(y);

    return 0;
}
```

I used the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2017" since the window's command prompt is giving me

```
nvcc fatal : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH
```

and the online solutions didn't work for me. Then I ran this command(the --compiler -options solved some of the errors already)

```
nvcc add.cu --compiler-options "-D _WIN64"
```

but the compiler is still giving me errors

```
C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(95): error: class template "std::_Is_function" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(139): error: class template "std::_Is_memfunptr" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(1824): error: class template "std::result_of" has already been defined

C:\Programming\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\type_traits(1824): error: class template "std::result_of" has already been defined
```

I have been looking for solutions. Seems like the other people with the similar problem were having issues with their included headers but my sample code is downloaded from the internet and the person who uploaded it didn't have any problem with it, which makes me confused on what part of the program have the problem.

P.S.: I don't know if my cuda is installed properly. Details:
I wasn't able to install cuda on my windows, the installation keeps telling me installation failed. Then I found a solution in this link at post #19: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1035535/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-9-2-does-not-work-with-visual-studio-2017-15-7-1/2
It seems to work fine but I don't know if it was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the same post in Nvidia CUDA forum: 
[Link Here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1037218/cuda-programming-and-performance/cuda-compilation-error-class-template-has-already-been-defined/post/5269827/#5269827)

I reinstalled multiple times with the method from the post but still having the same "class template" problems.

Then I reinstalled CUDA 9.1 and VS2017 ver 15.6.7 also with the same method and it finally works.

Further problems that I encountered is in the post too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Visual Studio 2019 and CUDA v10.1, however reinstalling made no difference. Originally I had Visual Studio 2012 installed, which is unsupported, so I updated versions, then I started seeing the template class redefinition errors as mentioned here - the solution I used was to change my environment variable for the c1.exe / c1.dll from the (x86) to (x64) directory and all of my errors disappeared.

was:
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\bin\Hostx64\x86

now: 
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\bin\Hostx64\x64