# nvcc cuda from command prompt not using gpu

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, gpu, nvcc

Trying to run a CUDA program from command prompt using nvcc, but it seems like GPU code is not running as expected. The exact same code runs successfully on Visual Studio and outputs the expected output.

```
nvcc -arch=sm_60 -std=c++11 -o test.cu test.exe
test.exe
```

Environment:
Windows 10,
NVIDIA Quadro k4200,
CUDA 10.2

Source Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

/* this is the vector addition kernel. 
  :inputs: n -> Size of vector, integer
           a -> constant multiple, float
           x -> input 'vector', constant pointer to float
           y -> input and output 'vector', pointer to float  */
__global__ void saxpy(int n, float a, const float x[], float y[])
{
  int id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x; /* Performing that for loop */ 
  // check to see if id is greater than size of array
  if(id < n){
     y[id] +=  a*x[id];
  } 
}

int main()
{
  int N = 256; 

  //create pointers and device
  float *d_x, *d_y; 

  const float a = 2.0f;

  //allocate and initializing memory on host
  std::vector<float> x(N, 1.f);
  std::vector<float> y(N, 1.f);

  //allocate our memory on GPU 
  cudaMalloc(&d_x, N*sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&d_y, N*sizeof(float));

  //Memory Transfer! 
  cudaMemcpy(d_x, x.data(), N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_y, y.data(), N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

  //Launch the Kernel! In this configuration there is 1 block with 256 threads
  //Use gridDim = int((N-1)/256) in general  
  saxpy<<<1, 256>>>(N, a, d_x, d_y);

  //Transfering Memory back! 
  cudaMemcpy(y.data(), d_y, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  std::cout << y[0] << std::endl;

  cudaFree(d_x);
  cudaFree(d_y);

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1
```

Expected Output

```
3
```

Things I tried

When I first tried to compile with nvcc, it had the same error as discussed here.

[Cuda compilation error: class template has already been defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182773/cuda-compilation-error-class-template-has-already-been-defined)

So I tried the suggested solution 
"now: D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\bin\Hostx64\x64"
and now it compiles and runs but the output is not as expected.

Comment: Not that it solves your issue, but `-o test.cu test.exe` or `-o test.exe test.cu`?

Comment: Also, `-arch=sm_60` is an incorrect arch specification for a Quadro K4200.  It should be `-arch=sm_30`.  When having trouble with a CUDA code, it's good practice to use [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).  If you are compiling this code using `-arch=sm_60` and running it on a Quadro K4200, you would have gotten some informative error output.  My suggestion is to use proper CUDA error checking *before* asking others for help.

Comment: Awesome. ```-arch=sm_30``` was the solution. I`ll do the error checking next time. Thank you for the great info.

Answer (score 1):

"Also, -arch=sm_60 is an incorrect arch specification for a Quadro K4200. It should be -arch=sm_30" by Robert Crovella